# Javascript context.closePath() method does not appear

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I have tried a lot to draw multiple circles in canvas but `context.closePath()` method does not appear

I have this code :

```
<script>
  var canvas = document.getElementById('mainCanvas-2');
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  for(var i=0;i<canvas.width;i++){    
      var centerX = i+Math.random()*canvas.width / 2;
      var centerY = i+Math.random()*canvas.height / 2;
      var radius = 20;
      context.beginPath();
      context.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
      context.shadowColor = 'white';
      context.shadowBlur = 45;
      context.shadowOffsetX = 0;
      context.shadowOffsetY = 0;
      context.fillStyle = 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)';
      context.fill();
      context.strokeStyle = none;
      context.stroke();
      context.// here closePath() method does not appear
  }
</script>
```

any help please,and thanks.

Comment: this `context.strokeStyle = none`  should be `context.strokeStyle = 'none'`, and `closePath` works I guess

Comment: thanks a lot,the problem was in context.strokeStyle = none that should be context.strokeStyle = 'none'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing `context.strokeStyle = none` to `context.strokeStyle = 'none'` solves it, cheers!

Demo below:

```js
  var canvas = document.getElementById('mainCanvas-2');
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  for(var i=0;i<canvas.width;i++){    
      var centerX = i+Math.random()*canvas.width / 2;
      var centerY = i+Math.random()*canvas.height / 2;
      var radius = 20;
      context.beginPath();
      context.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
      context.shadowColor = 'white';
      context.shadowBlur = 45;
      context.shadowOffsetX = 0;
      context.shadowOffsetY = 0;
      context.fillStyle = 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)';
      context.fill();
      context.strokeStyle = 'none';
      context.stroke();
      context.closePath();
  }
```

```html
<canvas id = "mainCanvas-2"></canvas>
```

Comment: Note that `closePath` still won't *appear* though, this method does a `lineTo(first_defined_point_of_the_path)`, so for a complete arc, this does nothing, and `stroke()` has been called before anyway.

Comment: yes i am waiting for it,i cannot accept until the time finish.